# Ruby on Rails : #any? returns wrong value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my models, I have users (`User`) and stories (`Story`), with the relation: `user has_many stories`.

I've noticed something strange in my shell:

```
(dev) user.stories.any?
=> true

(dev) user.stories
  Story Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "stories".* FROM "stories" WHERE "stories"."user_id" = 703  ORDER BY created_at ASC  [["user_id", 703]]
=> []

(dev) user.stories.any?
=> false
```

How does this work? Is this due to my code, or is it a bug of some sort in Rails and the way it queries the database?

Comment: @sawa what do you mean English punctuation ? Could you be more precise ? I'm obviously not a native speaker and sometimes I simply don't see where the mistake is.

Comment: Okay. Rules are different accross languages then. In french, we use spaces before and after when the punctuation mark is made of two parts.

Comment: possible defect in rails active relation? see source for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F which calls http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-empty-3F and returns true `if limit_value == 0` - might be an optimization to avoid hitting the database multiple times? I wonder if it behaves the same in  rails TEST environment?

Comment: Apparently, the bug is not present in TEST env.

Comment: Does this happen with a user that has just been fetched from a db ? How was user initialized?

Comment: Odd - never seen anything like that before - a minimum set of steps to reproduce would be interesting

Comment: Maybe it's due to the way the relation between the two models is defined.

In `user.rb`:
`has_many :stories, -> { order('created_at ASC') }`.

In `story.rb`:
`belongs_to :user, touch: true, counter_cache: true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I found (thanks to @house9) is to use:

```
user.stories.to_a.any?
user.stories.to_a.empty? # also works with empty?
```

This way, Rails is forced to make the query. And the overhead is quite low since doing `to_a.any?`several times only does the query once.

Or **better**, as @Jordan suggested, use:

```
user.stories.exists?
```

Comment: That will load all of the user stories into memory. If you don't need to use the stories information, just use `user.stories.count > 0`. It will perform a simple count operation on the db, instead of selecting all of its fields and serializing them into a ruby array.

Comment: Don't use `count`, use [`exists?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F). That's what it's for.

Comment: @Jordan Even better.

Comment: @Jordan not perfect though, as it does not return a boolean (therefore instantiating bigger objects)

Comment: Mmmh, my previous comment seems untrue for Rails 4.2.4. But the request is done each time the method is called (event if it is a small request)

Comment: sure `#exists?` returns a boolean. ?